# Dual monitors mirror each other

Tags: fedora, gnome, multi-monitor

So I have two monitors for this desktop and both of them currently mirror each other. I'm on Fedora 23 running a Radeon R9 390 8GB. I've tried the proprietary ATI drivers and when I reboot I get grub after selecting I get a black screen after a couple of flashes. I simply want the two monitors to act as two monitors and not mirror each other. Both my monitors are connect via DVI

[image]

Here is what xrandr outputs 
[image]

Comment: I recommend you to use `arandr`. It's just a gui, but allows you to setup monitors and their orientation very easy.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text contents of your configuration files, rather than posting screen capture images.

Comment: @MelBurslan which configuration files are you referring to?

Comment: @LevBystritskiy xrandr simply does not detect or know about my second monitor. However both of my monitors do display things they just mirror each other.